# Cycling through open windows in a desktop in windows 10 without thumbnailing

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way in windows 10 to define a keyboard shortcut that would allow the user to cycle through open windows in a given virtual desktop, while keeping the windows in their original sizes?

So basically I don't want to be shown a collection of open windows in reduced size as with Alt+Tab or the Task View, but rather flip between windows just like flipping between open tabs say in Chrome using Ctrl+Tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for switching backwards. This is here about since Windows 95.

Comment: Note that this shortcut will cover minimized windows as well which may significantly limit its utility depending on your purpose. (As for me, for example, I don't consider a minimized window "open".)

Comment: @Thenightmanager – it looks that your point is inadvertedly falling besides two different concepts and here it hits the wall. Typical users either use a mouse for task management and then they don't care about pressing Alt+something or they use a keyboard and then they don't minimize their windows, but only swap them.

Comment: @@miroxlav I don't see how your comment relates to mine, sorry. Regarding _your_ comment: all users (not just the "typical" ones) use what is made available to them. :-) and I wouldn't certainly venture to make statements about what typical users care about and what they don't. Maybe this wasn't the point of your comment, sorry if I missed again. :-)

Comment: @Thenightmanager – yeah, it wasn't the point. Rather than user I meant typical use scenarios – there are two tracks – and I believe that window minimization rarely meets keyboard switching. Your note was interesting anyway, you discovered a corner case which is not noticeable during discussed routines... 3.5 years the answer lays around without anyone noticing that. :)  Btw that thing does not seem to be an issue in Windows 10 build 1803. Minimized windows are skipped on Alt+(Shift+)Esc.